# How do I salvage an ancient Linux-hosted CollabNet Subversion Edge repository?

Tags: updates, svn

In our work development environment, we have an instance of an ancient version of CollabNet Subversion Edge, hosted on CentOS 5, with an inconvenient cascade of issues.

It's not authenticating users because the LDAP server it was pointing at has been decommissioned.

The admin console is in HTTPS-only mode.

The HTTPD attached to Subversion Edge doesn't offer a currently accepted version of TLS, so I need to update the installation to a more recent version.

The normal update workflow requires using the admin console.

The collabnet documentation online has a link to a separate site for the non-console update route.

The link has rotted.

The overall result is that Subversion is unusable, I can't use the admin console to fix it, and I can't find instructions for how to upgrade to something less antediluvian.

What's my way out of this problem?

EDIT: Turns out, I probably asked the wrong question. It looks like the best question to ask is "how do I get this repo onto an up to date platform?" and it looks like the answer is `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load`.

Comment: Standing up an older client machine with an outdated browser to get into the admin console might be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most effective strategy is probably to build a clean install and move the repos over with `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load`.

A user with a lot of custom scripts attached to their repo would need to rebuild those afterwards, since dump/load only move the repo contents.

That said, the commenter above's suggestion of using an older browser, or using about:config in Firefox to lower the required SSL/TLS version, is a good short-term strategy for regaining access to the admin console to fix the LDAP config while you make arrangements for updating systems.